# Ad Hoc reporting with SSRS and shared customer database

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a database with many customers inside of it.  Each row of the table has a customer ID that denotes which customer the data belongs to.

Is it possible to let the end user use Ad-Hoc reporting to build reports, but only let them see data associated to their customer id?

Answer (score 1):

In a report you can use the Built-in field UserID to return the current user's domain name e.g. MYDOMAIN\Username.

If you can create a table mapping customer Ids to domain names and join this to your main data table then you can  add a where clause into your dataset query such as

```
WHERE MappingTable.DomainUsername = @CurrentUser
```

In the report, create a hidden parameter called CurrentUser and set the value to Globals!UserID.Value

You need to be using Windows authentication in the report data source, where the report users credentials are being passed through to the data source, for this solution to work.

---

EDIT: I see I misread your original question, which was actually asking if it's possible to allow users to create ad hoc reports while restricting their view of the data. This scenario precludes any solution that is implemented in the reports themselves, since the users will be designing their own reports. Instead, you will probably need to implement some form of security layer in source database, for example using Views. You can use a similar approach to above if your users are using domain logins. For example your view could contain a reference to SUSER_NAME() to limit that data for that particular user.

Comment: This same concept can be used if the data is a 'customer' and not part of the domain. Just make the report parameter prompt/ask for the report user to enter their `CustomerId` to filter on, and have the parameter in the `WHERE` clause of the query, as above.

Comment: Agree with the above, although be aware this approach is susceptible to a customer entering an ID that is not their own (either accidentally or deliberately) and gaining access to data they should not see.

Comment: good point. If customers are external to the domain they would more than likely need some way to authenticate before getting to the report, whatever mechanism is used for this could be used to filter results as well e.g. if forms authentication is used and a session state is stored in a table, this would usually have a user id associated with it, in which case this user id can be used in an `INNER JOIN` to prevent records showing for anything other than the user of the current session.